# sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer returns every value as 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

i have these two arrays

```
train = np.array([4, 1, 2, 2,1, 3, 9, 3,5, 7, 5, 1])

test = np.array([3,6,3,1,8])
```

when i try to use the normalizer i get all values to be 1

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer

normalizer = Normalizer()

normalizer.fit(train.reshape(-1,1))

train_norm = normalizer.transform(train.reshape(-1,1))

test_norm = normalizer.transform(test.reshape(-1,1))

print(train_norm)
```

```
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

i tried to change the reshape method to be .reshape(1,-1) , but then i can't transform the test array with the error

```
ValueError: X has 5 features, but Normalizer is expecting 12 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Normalizer` normalizes each sample independently using some norm (by default l2). After normalization each sample's norm is 1 hence in your code each sample is scaled to 1 (because each sample is a scalar).

Moreover, according to the docs ([sklear.preprocessing.Normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer)), the fit method does nothing.

Comment: so how do I normalize all samples together using the same norm? what I am expecting is that the Normalizer understands the norm, then normalize it based on the train sample

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. In example, if you want your data to be similar to normal distribution, then calculate mean and stddev of train data and apply these values to all data (subtract mean and divide by stddev).